# DataGridViewImageColumn background is black

Tags: c#, datagridview, bitmap, background, datagridviewimagecolumn

I have a table, where one of the columns is of the image type. When using the "ImageLayout" attribute as "Stretch" the background is black. How can I change it to white?

[image: Image example]

I'm using the "SystemIcons" icon set converted to a bipmap.

```
 private Bitmap GetIcone()
 {
    return SystemIcons.Warning.ToBitmap();
 }
```

And inserting this way:

```
row.Cells["ColStatusIcone"].Value = GetIcone(status.icone);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: İf you want to change background color to white only Image cells:

```
     dataGridView1.CellFormatting += (x, y) =>
         {
             if (y.DesiredType == typeof(Image)){
                y.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
           } 
         };
```

You can try to change your image columns' color to white on ***CellFormattingEvent***. Try this:

```
 dataGridView1.CellFormatting += (x, y) =>
         {
             if (y.ColumnIndex != 1) //your image cell index
             {
                 return;
             }
             y.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
         };
```

Comment: I did the test, it paints any text cell, except the image cell

Comment: Pardon me. Please change if condition to " if (y.DesiredType == typeof(Image))".